# How can i make this room option work in my Flask chat application with SocketIO

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I'm creating a Flask chat app and got stuck when trying to use the room option when emit messages.

So far the application behaves in the following ways ('handle_message'):

- With broadcast on True the chat functionality is working application
  wide.
- Without the broadcast option the message is sent and instant seen only
  by sender.
- With room option no message is seen. Only by refresh but that takes
  the message out of storage.

Here is my code.

application.py

```
"""
SocketIO Handlers
"""
@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(data):
    """ When user joins a channel """
    username = session["user_name"]
    room = data['channel']
    join_room(room)
    emit('announcement', {
        "msg" : session["user_name"] + ' enters the channel'
    }, room=room)
    print('### ' +username + ' has entered the room -> ' + room)

@socketio.on('leave')
def on_leave(data):
    """ When user leavs a channel """
    username = session["user_name"]
    room = data['channel']
    leave_room(room)
    emit('announcement', {
            "msg" : session["user_name"] + ' leaved the channel'
    }, room=room)
    print('### ' + username + ' has left the room -> ' + room)

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_event(json):
    print('Received event from client:', str(json))
    emit('server response', json)

@socketio.on('handle_message')
def handle_message(data):
    """ Proces and transmit received messages """

    # handle data
    user = session['user_name']
    timestamp = data['timestamp']
    message = data['message']
    channel = data['channel']

    # print payload
    print('### Payload from user <' + user + '> ' + message + ' / ' + timestamp + '/ ' + channel)

    messages[channel].append([timestamp, user, message])

    # broadcast payload
    emit('server payload', {
        "user" : user,
        "timestamp" : timestamp,
        "msg" : message
    }, room=channel)
    print("### emit server payload send to room: " + channel)
```

client.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /*
        Setup and connection
    */

    // Connect client
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port)

    // Listen on connections
    socket.on('connect', function () {

        socket.emit('my event', {
            data: 'User Connected'
        });

        // Log connection in console 
        console.log('User connected')
    });


    /*
        Listeners
    */

    // Listen on server event
    socket.on('server response', function (msg) {
        console.log(msg)
    });

    // Listen on 'server announcements'
    socket.on('announcement', function (msg) {
        $("#messageList").append('<li>#' + msg.msg + '</li>');
        console.log('<-Announcement received: ' + msg.msg)
    })

    // Listen on 'server payload' and add to chat
    socket.on('server payload', function (msg) {
        $("#messageList").append('<li> ' + msg.timestamp + ' / [' + msg.user + ']: ' + msg.msg + '</li >');
        console.log('<- payload recieved:', msg.user, msg.timestamp, msg.msg);
    });

    /*
        Send data
    */

    // Send message to 'handle_message'
    $('#sendButton').on('click', function () {

        let msg = $('#message').val();
        let timestamp = new Date;
        let channel = $('#channelName').text();
        timestamp = timestamp.toLocaleTimeString();

        socket.emit('handle_message', {
            message: msg,
            timestamp: timestamp,
            channel: channel
        });
        $('#message').val('').focus();

        console.log('-> Sent payload to server')
    });

    // Send message when entering room
    $('ul#channelList li').on('click', function () {

        let cnl = $(this).text();
        console.log('clicket:' + $(this).text());
        socket.emit('join', {
            channel: cnl
        });

        console.log('-> Send emit join to server')
    })

    // Send announcement to 'left'
    $('#leaveRoom').on('click', function () {
        let cnl = document.querySelector("#channelName").textContent;
        socket.emit('leave', {
            channel: cnl
        });
    });

});
```

Does anyone has some pointers? I walked through the process a couple of times but am currently clueless how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have captured the logs I print server and client side. Did this in the 3 scenarios. To be clear i want it to work with the room=channel handle on socketio.on('sent payload')

```
Timeline

Info
Channel names (rooms): channel1 and channel2
Users: user1, user2, user3

// socket.io('handle_message') with broadcast=True

Server: socketio.on('join) / '### <user1> enters the room -> channel1'
Server: socketio.on('join) / '### <user2> enters the room -> channel1'
Server: socketio.on('join) / '### <user3> enters the room -> channel2'
Client1: socket.emit('handle_message') / client log: "-> Sent payload to server" 
Server: socketio.on('handle message') / server log: "### Payload from <user1> well hello / 15:23:41 / channel1"
Server: socketio.emit('server payload') / server log: "### Emit server payload send to room: channel1"
Client1: socketio.on('server payload') / server log: "<- payload recieved: <user1> 15:23:41 Wel hello"
Client2: socketio.on('server payload') / server log: "<- payload recieved: <user1> 15:23:41 Wel hello"
Client3: socketio.on('server payload') / server log: "<- payload recieved: <user1> 15:23:41 Wel hello"

Result: Message received from user1 and instantly displayed in chat. 
However when in other (channel2) the messages is also received and displayed.As expected by the Broadcast handle on True. 


// socket.io('handle_message') without Broadcast

Server: socketio.on('join) / '### <user1> enters the room -> channel1'
Server: socketio.on('join) / '### <user2> enters the room -> channel1'
Server: socketio.on('join) / '### <user3> enters the room -> channel2'
Client1: socket.emit('handle_message') / client log: "-> Sent payload to server" 
Server: socketio.on('handle message') / server log: "### Payload from <user1> Well hello broadcast is off / 15:47:56 / channel1"
Server: socketio.emit('server payload') / server log: "### Emit server payload send to room: channel1"
Client1: socketio.on('server payload') / server log: "<- payload recieved: <user1> 15:47:56 Well hello broadcast"
Client2: socketio.on('server payload') / Nothing
Client2: socketio.on('server payload') / Nothing

Result: Message received from user1 and only seen and displayed at user1 client

// socket.io('handle_message') with room=channel handle

Server: socketio.on('join) / '### <user1> enters the room -> channel1'
Server: socketio.on('join) / '### <user2> enters the room -> channel1'
Server: socketio.on('join) / '### <user3> enters the room -> channel2'
Client1: socket.emit('handle_message') / client log: "-> Sent payload to server" 
Server: socketio.on('handle message') / server log: "### Payload from <user1> Does it works in this room? / 15:57:23 / channel1"
Server: socketio.emit('server payload') / server log: "### Emit server payload send to room: channel1"
Client1: socketio.on('server payload') / Nothing
Client2: socketio.on('server payload') / Nothing
Client2: socketio.on('server payload') / Nothing

Result: Message send by client1 looks to be received by server and send out by emit by server payload but never to be received by one of the clients.
```

Comment: Try to add some more details about which behavior is not working and post the errors you are facing with you current code.

Comment: You need to be more clear on what's not working. For example, the code that you are showing is using `broadcast=True`, which you say works fine. So what is the version of this code that does not work? Have you looked at Socket.IO logs on the server and the client to see where are messages being dropped?

Comment: @Miguel 
Sorry first time here posting. I've added the logs i have from client and server side.

Comment: The logs that you are showing are prints from your own application. What I meant is that you should review the logs that the Socket.IO client and server produce. These are not enabled by default, they need to be enabled and are a great help when debugging problems like yours.